How not [?] to convert an enumerator into its corresponding string literal
Since I can't ask the author, I ask the community for suggestions: Why would you want to convert an enumerator into its corresponding string literal like done by the following example?
char* explainAPI(  
    _Inout_ char* sExplain,
    _In_ API_TYPE* enumerator
) {
    switch (*enumerator) {
    case API_LEFT:  sExplain = (char*)"API_LEFT ";  break;
    case API_RIGHT: sExplain = (char*)"API_RIGHT"; break;
    default:    sExplain = (char*)"  <???>  "; break;
    }
    return(sExplain)
}

In the background is a static library BLOB. Its copyrighted header (plain C) contains quite some
typedef enum _API_TYPE { API_LEFT = 2, API_RIGHT = 4 } API_TYPE;

Development environment is a Visual C++ Console Project.
I'm searching for reasons that I don't see, why the author didn't choose the simple solution, that I'd assume being chosen in the first attempt?
char* explainAPI(  
    _In_ API_TYPE enumerator
) {
    switch (enumerator) {
    case API_LEFT:  return (char*)"API_LEFT ";  
    case API_RIGHT: return (char*)"API_RIGHT";
    default:    return (char*)"  <???>  "; 
    }
}

Collection of similar suggestions

Apply Hanlon's razor.

_ names are reserved

Some people prefer a single point of return in functions; others don't.  Both viewpoints are valid.  The first function interface seems unnecessarily complex; there's no obvious benefit to passing the enumerator as a pointer instead of a value (and some disadvantage — you can't pass a constant to the function).  And the char * argument is singularly silly.  Assigning to the pointer argument as in the code does not change the pointed-at variable in the calling function, so it is pointless.  The return value should be const char * and then the casts could be removed.

I find both solutions similar. Both functions do exactly the same thing, except that the first one uses a char * passed as a parameter (which is unnecessary since it doesn't change the content). Ultimately, your solution is simpler. I think the author doesn't have your savvy.
